# animating a CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I have a CALayer on top of a UIView.

The UIView animates exactly how I want it to, however the PlayerView that is on top of it seems to "spawn" offscreen then animate to the position that the UIView started in ***and then*** it will animate to the UIViews frame.

I was wondering if there was any property of CALayers that could handle this issue automatically but I haven't found anything.

Here's the code for this:

```
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
     v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
     let v2 = UIView(frame: .zero)
    window.addSubview(v!);
    window.addSubview(v2)
    v?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    v?.layer.cornerRadius = (v?.frame.width)! * 0.025






    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }

    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    //        playerLayer.frame = playerView.frame

    playerLayer?.frame = (playerView?.bounds)!
    playerLayer?.masksToBounds = true

    playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill


    v?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)

    player?.play()
    player?.isMuted = true

    //looper
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100)
        self.player?.seek(to: t1)

        self.player?.play()
    }







    let superview = playerView?.superview

    v2.frame = (v2.convert((playerView?.frame)!, from: superview))
            v?.frame = (v?.convert((playerView?.frame)!, from: superview))!

    window.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: v!)
    window.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: v!)

            playerLayer?.frame = (v?.frame)!



                self.playerLayer?.frame = (self.v?.frame)!


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {



        self.window?.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: { (completed) in


        self.playerLayer?.frame = (self.v?.frame)!



    })


}
```

any suggestions?

EDIT:

I have included the updated code

```
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
    let v2 = UIView(frame: .zero)
    window.addSubview(v!);

    v?.addSubview(playerView2!)

    window.addSubview(v2)
    v?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    v?.layer.cornerRadius = (v?.frame.width)! * 0.025










    playerView2?.layer.cornerRadius = (playerView2?.bounds.width)! * 0.025

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }

    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    //        playerLayer.frame = playerView.frame

    playerLayer?.frame = (playerView2?.bounds)!
    playerLayer?.masksToBounds = true
    playerLayer?.cornerRadius = (playerView2?.bounds.width)! * 0.025

    playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill


    self.playerView2?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)

//        player?.play()
    player?.isMuted = true

    //looper
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100)
        self.player?.seek(to: t1)

//            self.player?.play()
    }










    self.playerView2?.frame = (self.v?.bounds)!
    self.playerLayer?.frame = (self.playerView?.bounds)!





    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {



        self.v?.frame = window.frame

        self.playerView2?.frame = (self.v?.frame)!

        self.playerLayer?.frame = (self.playerView2?.frame)!



        self.window?.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: { (completed) in




    })





}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an implicit animation when you set `playerLayer.frame`.

If you don't want any animation, temporarily disable implicit animations like this:

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.window?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completed) in
            let priorValue = CATransaction.disableActions()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            self.playerLayer?.frame = self.v!.frame
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(priorValue)
        })
```

If you do want to animate `playerLayer.frame`, then the best way is to create a `UIView` subclass that uses an `AVPlayerLayer` as its layer, like this:

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return AVPlayerLayer.self }
    private(set) lazy var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer = { self.layer as! AVPlayerLayer }()
}
```

Then you can use a `PlayerView` instead of a bare `AVPlayerLayer` and use UIKit animations. Since you can't initialize the `AVPlayerLayer` directly (`UIView` uses the default initializer to create its layer), you'll need to set the `PlayerView`'s player like this:

```
        playerView?.playerLayer = player
```

Comment: I was able to use your second suggestion and use a UIView with an AVPlayer, however, the UIView and the PlayerLayer still don't animate in unison. And whenever I try to force the animation, the playerLayer masks correctly to the UIView however it's an awkward jump rather than a smooth animation. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I would need to see your revised code and a better description of what's happening that you don't like.

Comment: It works somewhat it's just that the playerLayer doesn't animate along with v and playerView... The other two animate perfectly in unison. The current behavior is as if the line `self.playerLayer?.frame = (self.playerView2?.frame)!` reads a second or two after the other two started animating so it jumps to the frame rather than smoothly animating  the transition.